# convergence of the product of two divergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is it possible that the difference of two divergent series will converge?
let A and B be divergent series,
will AB converge?

Comment: What is your product $AB$?
i.e. when $A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, $B = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$, are you taking about Cauchy product
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}\right)$, product term by terms
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n b_n$ or what?

Comment: You use the words "product" and "difference" and it is also not quite clear whether you intend "series" or sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product need not always necessarily converge or diverge. Take for example,

$(1)$ The sequences $(-1)^n$ and $(-1)^{n+2}$ both diverge but their product, $(-1)^{2n+2}$ converges.

$(2)$ The sequences $n$ and $2n$ both diverge and their product, $2n^2$ diverges.

Comment: how about if AB converge, A  and  B maybe divergent or convergent?

Comment: This answer is about sequences, not series -- giving examples with series would be much better to answer the question.